# Firebase Rules: Allow user to read data only if user is included in a child node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am attempting to rewrite my database rules to only allow members of a specific 'collection' to access that collection only if that member is included in the `teams` list. Referring to the image attached below, this is what my rule currently looks like:

```
    {
        "rules": {
            "collection": {
                "$collection_id": {
                    "$teams" : {
                        ".read": "data.child('id').val() === auth.uid"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

However this doesn't seem to work and I believe it's incomplete. How can I update my rules to match this design structure? If any change in my structure is necessary to support this, do pitch that and I will attempt to update the current production data.

Comment: You have some sort of team id between "teams" and the id you need to reference.  This is going to cause your rules some problems.  You need to be able to reference the values with known named nodes, not variable named nodes.

Comment: @DougStevenson Assuming that I migrate existing rows to have an id for each `collection` in `collections`, how would that change my current rules?

Comment: Just to be clear - you're willing to accept an answer that proposes a change to your database?  If that's the case, please edit your question to say more about what your database structure is currently modeling so we can understand what your app is doing, and also state that you're open for changes (because right now it's suggesting that you're not open to changes).

Comment: @DougStevenson Sure, thanks Doug. Updated the question. I was hoping I wouldn't have to update the structure but it's fine I can manage with the migrations as long as I can set up this rule for max security :) Currently the production data looks like the ones described in the attached picture.

Comment: Well, I think you can do it without making changes.  I didn't realize that the team node and the id child of the node were actually the same thing, and actually an auth UID.  But you can simplify your database and rules by restructuring anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reach into the `teams` node like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "collection": {
            "$collection_id": {
                ".read": "data.child('teams').child(auth.uid).child('id').val() === auth.uid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Right now you have unnecessary redundancy in the `teams` node.  The id of the child node is repeated in its own child id.  You can simplify your database and rules if you simply set `teams/{teamId} = true` in the database, your rule could look like this instead to allow only users listed under teams to read the entire collection:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "collection": {
            "$collection_id": {
                ".read": "data.child(auth.uid).val() === true"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First suggestion works well! I'll append the id to all the data and we are good to go :) Thanks Doug, as always